# jQuery: get value of child element where other child element matches string

Tags: jquery, xml

I receive the following when querying a server using REST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widgets>
  <widget>
    <wid>wid1007</wid>
    <path>widgets-1007</path>
    <name>Frobnutter</name>
    <id>1</id>
    <version>0</version>
  </widget>
  <widget>
    <wid>wid1008</wid>
    <path>widgets-1008</path>
    <name>Roberts-Coupler</name>
    <id>2</id>
    <version>0</version>
  </widget>
</widgets>
```

I need to extract the value of "wid" from a "widget" using the known value of "id". What would this look like in jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = //your xml output

$(xml).find('wid').each(function() {
   var content = $(this).text();
   var id = $(this).siblings('id').text();
   //do something with each <wid> tags content
});
```

or

```
$('widget', xml).filter(function() {
    if ($(this).find('id').text() === '1') return $(this); 
}).find('wid');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/owiteq/edit#javascript,html

var xml = ...

```
$(xml).find("widget").each(function ()
        {
          if ($(this).find("id").text()==1)
         {
            alert($(this).find("wid").text());
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the xml to a variable lets say `rest_data`

```
$(rest_data).find("widget").each(function()
{
  if($(this).find("id").text() == "2")
  {
    //do something
    alert($(this).find("wid").text());
  }
});
```